# How to access tmpfs file under /dev/shm, created by user-space process, in a kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mmap

I created a file under /dev/shm (tmpfs) from user-space, I mmap'd this file into the process address space and pushed contents.
Now, how to map this file again under kernel virtual address space to access the contents written by the user-space process. Of course I know how to read it using filp_open() and vfs_read(), but I really want to access the contents using direct memory pointers similar to mmap() for user-space processes.
I want to do something similar to what's in mm/shmem.c, but instead of doing the mapping between the user-space VMA and the /SYSVXXX file, I want to do this with kernel virtual address VMA instead.
Can anyone help in that?

Thanks..

Comment: hmm have to think about that one ... :P nice question though +1  ... I take it that procfs interface isn't enough for you to read/write whatever you want from / to the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Only the code that implements `tmpfs` knows where its files' memory is.

You have to implement your own FS, or use one that allows you to define your own `mmap` implementation (like `procfs` or `sysfs`).